Which approach is correct for computing the partial derivative?
I am trying to calculate the Killing vectors and I need the partial derivative of $ \chi $ with respect to $ X_1 $ within a embedding of 4-dimensional de Sitter space. The coordinates in this embedding satisfy the constraint:
\begin{equation}
-T^2 + X_1^2 + X_2^2 + X_3^2 + X_4^2 = R^2,
\end{equation}
where $ T $ represents a time-like coordinate, and $ R $ is the spatial radius related to the intrinsic coordinates.
The embedding coordinates $ (T, X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) $ correspond to the intrinsic coordinates $ (t, \chi, \theta, \phi) $ as shown below:
\begin{equation}
T = R \sinh\left(\frac{t}{R}\right),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
X_1 = R \cosh\left(\frac{t}{R}\right) \cos \chi,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
X_2 = R \cosh\left(\frac{t}{R}\right) \sin \chi \cos \theta,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
X_3 = R \cosh\left(\frac{t}{R}\right) \sin \chi \sin \theta \cos \phi,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
X_4 = R \cosh\left(\frac{t}{R}\right) \sin \chi \sin \theta \sin \phi,
\end{equation}
I am finding two different answers for $ \frac{\partial \chi}{\partial X_1} $ when I approach the calculation in two different ways, Using
\begin{equation} \cos \chi = \frac{X_1}{\sqrt{R^2 + T^2}}
\end{equation} and
\begin{equation} \cos \chi = \frac{X_1}{\sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2 + X_3^2 + X_4^2}}
\end{equation}
Could someone help clarify which approach is correct and why there might be a discrepancy between the two methods?
Thank you!

This is similar to the embedding of $S^2$ (with its spherical coordinates $\varphi,\theta$) into $\mathbb R^3,.$ The $z$-coordinate is a function only of $\theta,.$ Recall $z=\cos\theta,.$ The radius is fixed at one. This corresponds to your equation for $X_1,.$ Can you draw the conclusion?

Step by step. So far you asked only about $\frac{\partial \chi}{\partial X_1}$ nothing about $X_2,.$ If you are still unsure whether $X_1$ is only a function of $\chi$ another hint: are $T,R$ constant or not when you take that partial derivative?

@KurtG. Sorry I had to delete the previous comment. I am not sure if I have got this right. So, $X_1$ is a function of $\chi$ and t? and $X_2$ is a function of $\theta$, $\chi$ and t? and tan $\phi$=$\frac{X_4}{X_3}?$ The reason I came up with this is because t is a function of T only, so cosh ($\frac{t}{R}$) is fixed by the knowledge of T only. so in that sense $\cos \chi = \frac{X_1}{\sqrt{R^2 + T^2}}$ is correct?

@KurtG. Yes, R and T are constants when I take that partial derivative.

$R,T$ are constants. Instead of firing off three questions please proceed with your derivations. I will then check.

@KurtG. I got $\frac{\partial \chi}{\partial X_1} = -\frac{1}{\sin \chi \cdot R \cosh\left(\frac{t}{R}\right)}$ and $
\frac{\partial}{\partial X_1} = -\frac{1}{\sin \chi \cdot R \cosh\left(\frac{t}{R}\right)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \chi}
$, $
\frac{\partial}{\partial T} = \frac{1}{\cosh \left(\frac{t}{R}\right)} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}
$. So, for the killing vector$
L_{T X_1} = T \frac{\partial}{\partial X_1} + X_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial T}
$, and $
L_{T X_1} = R \cos \chi \frac{\partial}{\partial t} - \csc \chi , \coth \left(\frac{t}{R}\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial \chi}
$

The partiaĺ derivatives look right. Should we not see the metric first in the Greek coordinates to be able to talk about Killing vector fields?

@KurtG. Yes we can do it that way, the metric is $\mathrm{d}s^2 = -\mathrm{d}t^2 + R^2 \cosh^2\left(\frac{t}{R}\right) \left( \mathrm{d}\chi^2 + \sin^2 \chi , \mathrm{d}\theta^2 + \sin^2 \chi , \sin^2 \theta , \mathrm{d}\phi^2 \right)$ but solving it partial differential equations in a bit tedious.

@KurtG. So, the hyperboloid embedded in the 5-D Minkowski space has $SO(1,4)$ symmetry. The generators of which in the extrinsic co-ordinates are given by $L_{T X^i} = T \frac{\partial}{\partial X^i} + X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial T}$ and $L_{X^i X^j} =  X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial X^j} - X^j \frac{\partial}{\partial X^i}$. Now I want to express them in terms of the intrinsic co-ordinates. Is this approach correct?

Intuitively, yes. I think this de Sitter space (or more simply the embedding of $S^2$ I mentioned earlier) are perfect examples of checking if both approaches agree.

I have added an answer to a question about $S^2$ to show how it works.

@KurtG. I cannot add a comment to that answer but I can you please add some insight on why we have two expressions for $\partial_{\theta}$? I mean can we conclude from that on $S^2$, $\cos\theta\cos\phi,\partial_x+\cos\theta\sin\phi,\partial_y=0$ ?

@KurtG. For the $S^2$, why is it wrong to use $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$ and sin$^2 \theta$=$x^2+y^2$ so we would get a an expression for $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}$. This gives $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}= \frac{cos \phi}{sin \theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}+\frac{sin \phi}{cos \theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$. cos $\theta$= z but as we have a constraint relation, z can be expressed in terms of x and y as well. I am confused here.

I wrote that you can eliminate one of the three $x,y,z$ or $\partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_z,.$ Ditto $dx,dy,dz,.$ Which one you choose depends on the convenience in a specific case.  Yesterday, in the rotation around the $x$-axis case it was most convenient to eliminate $\partial_x$ for geometrically obvious reasons.

@kurtG Can you please take a look at this question here?
